# How to prove equal cardinality of arbitrary subset and its closure, in this proof of downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem?

Tags: first-order-logic

From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Downward_part) wikipedia article:

> For each first-order $\sigma $-formula $\varphi(y,x_{1}, \ldots,
> > x_{n}) \,,$ the axiom of choice implies the existence of a function
> :$f_{\varphi}: M^n\to M$
>
> such that, for all $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n} \in M$, either
> :$M\models\varphi(f_{\varphi} (a_1, \dots, a_n), a_1, \dots, a_n)$
>
> or :$M\models\neg\exists y\, \varphi(y, a_1, \dots, a_n) \,.$
>
> Applying the axiom of choice again we get a function from the
> first-order formulas $\varphi$ to such functions $f_{\varphi} \,.$
>
> The family of functions $f_{\varphi}$ gives rise to a preclosure
> operator $F $ on the power set of $M $ :$F(A) = \{f_{\varphi}(a_1,
> > \dots, a_n) \in M \mid \varphi \in \sigma ; \, a_1, \dots, a_n \in A \} $
>
> for $A \subseteq M \,.$
>
> Iterating $F $ countably many times results in a closure operator
> $F^{\omega} \,.$ Taking an arbitrary subset $A \subseteq M$ such that
> $\left\vert A \right\vert = \kappa$, and having defined $N = F^{\omega}(A) \,,$ one can see that also $\left\vert N \right\vert = \kappa \,.$

I can see that $\kappa \leq \left\vert N \right\vert$ on account of properties of closure operators, yet $\left\vert N \right\vert \leq \kappa$ seems less obvious to me.

It seems to me each $f_{\varphi}$ maps $A^{n_{\varphi}}$ to $M_{\varphi} \subseteq M$, where $\left\vert M_{\varphi} \right\vert \leq \left\vert A^{n_{\varphi}} \right\vert = \kappa^{n_{\varphi}}$.

Since we iterate until closure, this seems to give rise to $\left\vert N \right\vert \leq \sum_{\varphi \in \sigma} \kappa^{n_{\varphi}^{\omega}}$, where $n_{\varphi}$ is raised to $\omega$ or countable infinity.

I am not sure this is a correct approach, or how to avoid $\kappa < \left\vert N \right\vert$.

Edit: It does say later in the proof that $\left\vert F(A) \right\vert \leq \left\vert A \right\vert + \left\vert \sigma \right\vert + \aleph_0$. However, I can't see how that can be guaranteed.

Comment: First suppose for simplicity that $A$ is infinite and $\vert\sigma\vert\le\aleph_0$. Can you show $\vert F(A)\vert=\vert A\vert$? The more complicated expression in your edit is just the "assumption-free" version of this calculation. The next point is to show that the countable union of sets of size $\lambda$ has size $\lambda$ again as long as $\lambda$ is infinite.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I suppose $\left\vert F(A) \right\vert \leq \sum_{\varphi \in \sigma} \kappa^{n_{\varphi}} \leq \left\vert \sigma \right\vert \kappa^{{max}_{\sigma}(n_{\varphi})}$. It seems the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ can be considered of order $\aleph_0^2$ and countable, however there is no bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ so I am not sure how to approach the powers of $\kappa$.

Comment: "there is no bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$" There **is** a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. ([Not a *continuous* one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), but that doesn't matter.) Maybe you're confusing $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $2^\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I figured any function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ should either increase or decrease in two independent directions, arriving and departing along each such direction at every point, hence no bijection would be possible since $\mathbb{R}$ has only two orientations. I could have sworn I read in some reputable source that invertibility in such a case was trivially impossible, upon which I hatched the former proof. However, now I am surprised to read of space-filling curves, including Peano curves.

Comment: In fact **every** infinite set $X$ satisfies $\vert X\vert=\vert X^2\vert$ (at least, assuming the axiom of choice).